# Why does i3 Window Manager make a blank section?

Tags: linux, window-manager

Once in a while, my i3 Window Manager makes a blank tile that only shows the desktop background. I don't know what causes this. Maybe it's a keystroke I am inadvertently making.

It ruins the whole workspace because:

- there is a significant portion gone (remaining windows smaller, and just doesn't look right)
- because it can't be closed, I cannot close the workspace

I can move my existing apps to other workspaces, but sometimes I'd like to actually use the ruined workspace number.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you try the following the next time this happens? Open a terminal, close all other windows (mainly to reduce output and for your privacy's sake) and run `i3-msg -t get_tree | json_pp > /tmp/i3_tree.json` in the terminal. `/tmp/i3_tree.json` will then contain a list of all open windows and workspaces and that may give some indication about the problem. Also as this is probably a bug,please consider [posting it on i3's bug tracker](http://newticket.i3wm.org/)

Comment: Fantastic advice. I am able to see the the problematic node is called "Desktop". This makes sense, however, I am now researching how to close it. At least I know what I am looking for. Does anyone know how to close "Desktop"? I've tried using the keyboard to focus on that tile and "kill" it with my i3 key-binding. No luck with that.

Comment: If you use `xprop` or `xwininfo` (just run from terminal and then click into the "Desktop" window) you may get a bit more information on where it comes from.

Comment: This is what happened when I tested gnome flashback, ala `exec --no-startup-id gnome-flashback`. If anyone has the OP's problem and has that configured, try disabling